# combining two data frames grouped by dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two date frames grouped by different dates, but both have the same yyyy-mm format

```
przyjecia.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Data przyjęcia']).dt.to_period('M'))['NIP dłużnika'].nunique()
```

```
gw.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Data GW']).dt.to_period('M'))['NIP dłużnika'].nunique()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2fk2.png)

|  Data GW          |
| 2023-01  | 345    |
| 2023-02  | 234    |
| 2023-03  | 344    |

Data przyjęcia
| -------- | -------- |
| 2023-01  |  1736    |
| 2023-02  |  1614    |
| 2023-03  |  1728    |

I need to have in one table the following columns: Date, count from Data przyjęcia, count from Data gw, percentage count Data gw/count Data przyjęcia

| Date     | Count Data przyjęcia | Count Data GW | Column B |
| -------- | --------             |               |          |
| 2023-01  | 1736                 |   345         |  20%     |
| 2023-02  | 1614                 |   234         |  14%     |
| 2023-03  | 1728                 |   344         |  20%     |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two dataframes based on time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68167144/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-based-on-time)

Comment: the only problem is that in my case I have two different columns with dates, one df is 'Data przyjęcia' and the other is 'Data GW'

Comment: Could you just rename one of the column ? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: how can i use rename here 'Data GW' to 'Data przyjęcia'
gw.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Data GW']).dt.to_period('M'))['NIP dłużnika'].nunique()